# Are Shared hosting IP OK for Mandrill API Requests?

Tags: api, hosting, mandrill, dedicated-server

Are Shared hosting IP OK for Mandrill API Requests?

I'm trying figure out if a Nightmare is true or simply pure work overload. :)

Mandrill comes with a Shared and Dedicated IP Options for sending out emails. What I fully 100% agree with. But do I need a Dedicated IP for sending out API Requests to Mandrill? Or can Shared  Hosting  IP work as a starting point. (e.g Bluehost / Hostgator Shared Plans ).

Is there a possibility, that tow Account will use the same IP and lead to very Angry Mandrill? :{

I am planing to apply for a Dedicated IP. But would like to not rush with buy every feature to quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mandrill dedicated IP option is an IP that is *only* used for sending your emails. You don't make API calls to that address.  You would still make API calls to the same API endpoint described in the [Mandrill API docs](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/) - with a dedicated IP, once we receive and process your mail, we would then route it over a dedicated IP address instead of the shared pool of sending IP addresses.  All of the sending IPs are *only* used for sending emails. They aren't used for other portions of the application or API.

Comment: If I my understanding is correct. I Initialize all API requests with a **"with a dedicated IP"** at my Hosting Account and then Mandrill would process it through a Shared Pool/IP address. Depending on a Plan. Problem Solved. :)